# Can I make a repeated jQuery next() by for loop?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors, siblings, nextsibling

I wanna select some sibling elements.
So I used jQuery .next() but I don't know how to repeat.

```js
// Repeat 3 times
$('#after').next().addClass('selected');
$('#after').next().next().addClass('selected');
$('#after').next().next().next().addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li id="after" data-num="3">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>  
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How can I make a repeated jQuery next() as specified value by for loop, like this?
(of course this is not working.)

```
$('#after')
  for(var i=0; i<$('#after').data('num'); i+=1){
    .next().addClass('selected')
  }
;
```

Comment: You might like to update the question with what you are expecting to happen - eg that just `<li>6</li>` will be selected (which is how I see the question, but others obviously don't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `next()` use `nextAll()`

```
$('#after').nextAll("li").addClass('selected');
```

You do not need to iterate over all the elements. `nextAll()` will select all the `sibling` elements down to the source element in the `DOM` tree.

<strike>If you want to do with out looping statements, then you have to do it like,</strike>

```
var srcElem = $("#after");
var srcIndex = srcElem.index() + 1; 
var index = +srcElem.data("num");
secElem.closest("ul")
         .find("li:gt("+ (index-1) +"):lt("+ (srcIndex + index) +")")
           .addClass('selected');
```

Using loop will be the best approach here, but use it in an optimized way,

```
 var src = $('#after');
 for (var i = 0, len = +src.data('num'); i < len; i++) {
   src = src.next("li").addClass('selected');
   if (!src.length) { break; }
 }
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tc7fjens/1/)

Comment: I wanna select as specified value on 'data-num' attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I don't completely understand whole code, but I understand what you mean.
`
var src = $('#after'),
 len = src.data('num'),
 i;

if (src.length) {
 for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
  src = src.next("li").addClass('selected');
 }
}`

Thank you :)